# Filter out dependencies in Application Insights

Tags: c#, azure

I want to filter out dependency calls in Application Insights. I want to check if the call is to one of some specific hosts. Following [this approach](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/request-filtering-in-application-insights-with-telemetry-processor/) I've come up with this:

```
public class ApplicationInsightsFilter : ITelemetryProcessor
{
    ...

    IgnoredHosts = new List<string>
    {
        "foo.queue.core.windows.net",
        "foo.blob.core.windows.net",
        "bar.queue.core.windows.net",
        "bar.blob.core.windows.net"
    };

    public void Process(ITelemetry item)
    {
        var request = item as DependencyTelemetry;

        if (request?.Name != null)
        {
            Uri uri = Uri.TryCreate(request.Name, UriKind.Absolute, out uri) ? uri : null;
            if (uri != null && IgnoredHosts.Contains(uri.Host))
                return;
        }

        Next.Process(item);
    }
}
```

And in `Program.cs`:

```
public static void ConfigureLogging()
{
    ...
    TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryProcessorChainBuilder
                .Use(next => new ApplicationInsightsFilter(next))
                .Build();
}
```

This works fine while debugging, bot not in production. In production these calls are still logged.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that if you have an `ApplicationInsights.config` file, you also have to insert the processor in this:

```
<TelemetryProcessors>
  <Add Type="MyWebApplication.ApplicationInsightsFilter, MyWebApplication">
  </Add>
</TelemetryProcessors>
```

Even though the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-filtering-sampling#filtering-itelemetryprocessor) says:

> Alternatively, you can initialize the filter in code.